# How do I access files on Bluemix Object Storage from Python on Data Science Experience?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, object-storage, data-science-experience

I'd like to copy a file to local memory on DSX so that I can create a pandas dataframe using read_csv.  I don't want to use the given "insert to code" option because that assumes column headers and it isn't as pretty to code.  Here is my code:

```
import swiftclient

IBM_Objectstorage_Connection = swiftclient.Connection(key=objStorCred['password'],
                                                  authurl=objStorCred['auth_url'],
                                                  auth_version='3',
                                os_options={"project_id": objStorCred['projectId'],
                                            "user_id": objStorCred['userId'],
                                            "region_name": objStorCred['region']})

x = IBM_Objectstorage_Connection.get_account()
```

I've tried the object storage admin credentials and the credentials for the container.  Neither work.  I'm trying to copy what was done in [this](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/using-ibm-object-storage-in-bluemix-with-python/) tutorial, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Here is my error:

```
Authorization Failure. Authorization failed: The resource could not be found. (HTTP 404)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try the code snippet from this tutorial from the community area: https://datascience.ibm.com/exchange/public/entry/view/07db16e78e1722931e27c074ebe343ae

Comment: That uses the same logic from the "insert into code" functionality.  I would like to access it in the same way that the [this tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/using-ibm-object-storage-in-bluemix-with-python/) access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you take a look at the `get_file_content(credentials)` method mentioned in the following notebook:

https://apsportal.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/461e1a46-243c-4264-98fb-653884ed27f5/view?access_token=e5eb80cb75eae7e2d8ac4306eece1d1345a6c59a180eb284fb79aa04d3ccb7fe

```
content_string = get_file_content(credentials_1)
precipitation_df = pd.read_csv(content_string)
```

I have used it many times before. Hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, but because the csv doesn't have headers, I lose one of the rows and have to overwrite the headers.  The solution I was looking for was the ability to download from object storage, then use read_csv on the local copy.

Comment: I didn't notice.  It did help!  Thank you!  This wasn't exactly what I was asking, but it was a way to get to what I wanted.  I'll mark this as answered.